# Change color of a single line in a p tag and then change it back

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, logging

Please don`t get me wrong, I know that I can put a span tag with a class in the paragraph, and then change the color of it. But that is not what I need.

My application is showing some log files in the browser. I am loading the data (from my log file) with AJAX in a p tag. Now i want to change the color of the lines which contains "ERROR" to red. But i need the other lines to be black. So if I write into a span tag, all the errors are on top of the p tag. That is also not what i want.

So for example: I have an info log, an error log, and again an info log.
My lines should have the colors: black, red, black

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please show as an example of the log and what you've tried so far

Comment: how do you identify it is an error line?

Comment: Show us code so, that we could help you out. :)

Comment: you must have given a condition to identify the error log . just specfy the css there with jquery

Comment: you cant set css to a part of a p tag. you have to surround the text you want to style with a tag for designing it.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KynKK/) what you looking for?

Comment: For a good answer you have to give us more information. Show us an example of the resulting html. What is your log data from ajax call look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said "lines" so I'm assuming the data is separated with line breaks, such as `\n`. To make those lines in the paragraph, you'll have to convert them to `<br>`, and to avoid having `<` and `&` misinterpreted in the text of the entries, you'll need to turn them into character entities. So we may as well wrap the error lines in spans, see comments:

```js
// The data
var text =
  "INFO: Blah blah blah\n" +
  "ERROR: OMG, something went wrong\n" +
  "WARNING: Don't run with scissors\n" +
  "ERROR: Knife inserted in electrical socket.\n" +
  "INFO: More blah";

// First, encode entities
text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");

// Split into lines
var lines = text.split("\n");

// Wrap errors in error span
lines = lines.map(function(line) {
  return line.startsWith("ERROR:") ? "<span class=error>" + line + "</span>" : line;
});

// Combine with <br> and put in the paragraph
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = lines.join("<br>");
```

```css
.error {
  color: #d00;
}
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

That's verbose for the purposes of clarity. Short version:

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =
  text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;")
  .split("\n")
  .map(function(line) {
    return line.startsWith("ERROR:") ? "<span class=error>" + line + "</span>" : line;
  })
  .join("<br>");
```

```js
var text =
  "INFO: Blah blah blah\n" +
  "ERROR: OMG, something went wrong\n" +
  "WARNING: Don't run with scissors\n" +
  "ERROR: Knife inserted in electrical socket.\n" +
  "INFO: More blah";

document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =
  text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;")
  .split("\n")
  .map(function(line) {
    return line.startsWith("ERROR:") ? "<span class=error>" + line + "</span>" : line;
  })
  .join("<br>");
```

```css
.error {
  color: #d00;
}
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice way. I have just one problem left: what can I do, if the lines doesn`t start with ERROR? First is the date time...

Comment: @S.stone: Just replace `line.startsWith("ERROR:")` with anything that results in a truthy value if it's a line you want to highlight. For instance, for "ERROR" (in all caps) anywhere in the line: `line.indexOf("ERROR") != -1` (or on modern JavaScript engines, `line.includes("ERROR")`). Case-insensitive (matching ERROR or error or ErrOr, etc.): `/error/i.test(line)`.

Comment: @S.stone :-) Post a question, someone will answer it, even if it's not me. Lots of good people here. (I *really* need to get my head into my work...)

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but there's no direct way to do that as all text within opening and closing HTML tags is considered to be a Text Node (as a whole) and there are no CSS selectors that can do what you are trying to accomplish. My only suggestion for you is to use JavaScript to parse the received text (possibly within the "done" ajax event) to dynamically add the aforementioned tags with its corresponding CSS class.